# Restarting waitress-serve

Tags: python, waitress

I'm using waitress-serve on my production server to run my flask application.
However, each time I want to change the python code, I need to manually find and kill waitress before restarting it.

```
$ ps -eaf | grep waitress
$ kill waitress_pid
$ waitress-serve --call --listen=127.0.0.1:5000 my_app:create_app &
```

Is there a smarter way to restart waitress serve ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a good solution for this aswell, but the only solution that I came up with was to create a terminal one-liner.

It looks like this:

```
kill -9 $(pgrep waitress) ; waitress-serve --call --listen=127.0.0.1:5000 my_app:create_app
```

`pgrep waitress` will yield the PID-number wich get killed right away. After that the `waitress-serve`-command will start your server.

I guess you also can create an alias in the .bashrc file or a independent bash-script could also do the job.